# How to capture session end time in Informatica

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on Informatica 9.6 version.

I am trying to load records which are greater than session endtime.

How can I load parameter file with `session_end_time`?

When I pass `timestamp>=$$session_end_time` how to load parameter file with `session_end_time`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to refer to the end time of your previous session run. There is no such variable available, so you will need to store a value somewhere (a paramfile or database) at the end of your session run. And read it and use to set a variable in a separate session before the main one.

Comment: Thank you Mac, How can I store that value(session end time) ,is it manual entry or I need to write any logic.Can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to create a separate session. Give it a try and come back in case of issues. Please, do not expect a tutorial.